# Excel sumifs with part of criteria field

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering is there a way to sum on part of criteria field. I.e. beginning in A1 I have

```
as    100  
dc    200  
ax    300  
ak    130
```

How do I sum if cells in column A start with "a"? Tried these formulas, they do not complain about syntax, but none of them return desired result. I need to do it with SUMIFS as in real life I actually have multiple criteria.

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B4,A1:A4,LEFT(A1:A4,1) & "=a")
=SUMIFS(B1:B4,A1:A4,"=" & LEFT(A1:A4,1)="a")
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excel sumif function supports wildcards for text fields, so you can use "=a*" as the condition.